# How To Pass Button Properties from XAML to .CS File

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

I am new to c#. i want to pass button properties from xaml file to .cs file. How can i do it?

```
<Button Content="myButton" x:Name="{Binding assignment_title}" click="btn_Click()"/>
```

Here I want to pass 'Name' of button to .cs file. Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

The properties of a control are exposed to your code behind (.cs) automagically. In your case you're binding the `Button`'s name which is confusing, I feel like you're actually trying to bind the `Content` property and that you've placed the name in the `Content` property by mistake. Try this:

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" Content="{Binding assignment_title}" click="btn_Click()"/>
```

and then in your code behind you can do:

```
myButton.Content = "Button Clicked!"
```

and it will update the content of the `Button`.

Comment: it generates error that Error Error The name 'mybutton' does not exist in the current context C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WpfApplication3\WpfApplication3\MainWindow.xaml.cs 63 13 WpfApplic‌​ation3

Comment: In Oren's example, it's "myButton" with a capital B on Button. In your error it's written "mybutton". Is that normal ? Did you check that the spelling of your button's name match what you wrote in the code-behind file ?

Answer (score 0):

In .cs file you can access control property like controlName.Property (In your case myButton.Name).

Comment: @petchchirajan    it generates error that Error Error The name 'mybutton' does not exist in the current context C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WpfApplication3\WpfApplication3\MainWindow.xaml.cs 63 13 WpfApplication3

Answer (score 0):

Oren's answer is correct,

But i would suggest you look into using ViewModels with your xaml Views, and look into the MVVM pattern and using as less code behind as possible.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

I use the mvvm with Caliburn.Micro.

http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/

That does all the bindings using conventions.